# GFORTH: alternative function to "fdepth"? = returning the current height of the float stack

Tags: stack, depth, gforth

I would like to know the depth of the float stack at a period of time when a word is called..

see https://gforth.org/manual/Examining-data.html#index-fdepth_0028--_002d_002d-_002bn--_0029-floating

the sequence is

```
..
F.S (result: <3> 5.000000000000E0 2.000000000000E0 2.000000000000E0 )
FDEPTH
F.S (result: <3> 5.000000000000E0 2.000000000000E0 2.000000000000E0 )
..
```

I dont see what FDEPTH is doing: I was expecting the value 3.0e would have been introduced at the float stack. But the stack did not change.
I suppose this is an issue with FDEPTH gforth (maintener is contacted).

Has anybody a proposal how to define an alternative function to FDEPTH? (bringing into the stack the value which is the height of the stack).

Update: see answer below. The result of fdepth was in another stack. NOT the float stack.

Comment: The result of "fdepth" is in another stack; not the float stack. Topic solved. .. command -> gforth <cr> 
.. output -> Gforth 0.7.3, Copyright (C) 1995-2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Gforth comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `license'
Type `bye' to exit
.. command -> 1.0e 2.0e 3.0e 4.0e 5.0e 6.0e 5.0e  4.0e  <cr> .. output -> ok
.. command -> f.s <cr> .. output -> <8> 1.0E0 2.0E0 3.0E0 4.0E0 5.0E0 6.0E0 5.0E0 4.0E0  ok
.. command -> fdepth  <cr> .. output -> ok                              
.s <1> 8  ok